# How to store a string from a textbox and then use that string in C#

Tags: c#, get, set

it's a simple application that is supposed to keep a record of student information. On the form there are text boxes for information such as name, course etc and three buttons "SET", "CLEAR" and "GET". The set button is supposed to take user input and store it as a string, the CLEAR button clears all the text boxes and GET button is supposed to bring the data back into the text boxes.

```
namespace Project1

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }



     public void SetBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         string firstname = FirstNameTxtBox.Text;
         string lastname = LastNameTxtBox.Text;
         string course = CourseTxtBox.Text;
         string mno = MNoTxtBox.Text;
         string yrmark = YrMarkTxtBox.Text;
     }

     private void ClrBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         FirstNameTxtBox.Text = String.Empty;
         LastNameTxtBox.Text = String.Empty;
         CourseTxtBox.Text = String.Empty;
         MNoTxtBox.Text = String.Empty;
         YrMarkTxtBox.Text = String.Empty;
     }

     private void GetBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         FirstNameTxtBox.Text = firstname;
         LastNameTxtBox.Text = lastname;
         CourseTxtBox.Text = course;
         MNoTxtBox.Text = mno;
         YrMarkTxtBox.Text = yrmark;


     }

     private void ShowBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         {
             phd newWin = new phd();
             newWin.Show();
         }
     }




 }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should post the error you are getting. But anyway, the problem you have there is that you are declaring your variables in `SetBttn_Click`, which means they will only exist inside that method. That's called local variables.

To do what you are attempting you need to declare the variables as fields in the form itself:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string firstname, lastname, course, mno, yrmark;
    ...
```

That way they will be shared amongst all methods in your class. I would also suggest naming them differently to set them apart from local variables. Some prefix the names with an underscore, myself I prefer something like `m_FirstName`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating the variable inside the method. In your `Set` method you are creating the **local(to the method)** variable and you can not read it in your other method(Get) because that variable is accessible in the Set method only.

Solution : Use a variable defined outside your method and store and read from that. Here i am defining a variable in the class level. This is accessible in all the methods. You can set a value in one method and read the value in another method.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private string _firstName;
  public void SetBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     //Setting the value to the class level scoped variable.
      _firstName = FirstNameTxtBox.Text;
  }
  private void GetBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    //Reading the value from the class level scoped variable.
     FirstNameTxtBox.Text = _firstName ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to set your strings outside of your function so there not local.

```
string firstname;
string lastname;
 string course;
string mno;
 string yrmark;
 public void SetBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         firstname = FirstNameTxtBox.Text;
         lastname = LastNameTxtBox.Text;
         course = CourseTxtBox.Text;
         mno = MNoTxtBox.Text;
         yrmark = YrMarkTxtBox.Text;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must move the declaration of the strings out of the methode:

```
// Declaration:
private string firstname = "";
private string lastname = "";
private string course = "";
private string mno = "";
private string yrmark = "";

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void SetBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    firstname = FirstNameTxtBox.Text;
    lastname = LastNameTxtBox.Text;
    course = CourseTxtBox.Text;
    mno = MNoTxtBox.Text;
    yrmark = YrMarkTxtBox.Text;
}
```